# PHP form action and submittal

Tags: php, forms, form-submit, onsubmit

I just wrote my first PHP code or attempted to anyways. A very simple form for email submission. It's not submitting right however. Can anyone guide me towards where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Here is the form code on this .html page

```
<form action="request-info.php" method="post" name="request-info">

<input name="name" type="text" value="Name">

<input name="email" type="text" value="E-mail Address">

<p>More information for</p>
<input name="family" type="radio" value="Family Member">Family
<br>
<input name="friend" type="radio" value="Friend">Friend
<br>
<input name="myself" type="radio" value="Myself">Myself
<br>
<input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit"> | <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Here is what I have on the action page. I think this is where I may be wrong. Should I have an something in here relating to the submit button?

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$family = $_POST['family'];
$friend = $_POST['friend'];
$myself = $_POST['myself'];
$to = "example@example.com";
$subject = "Information Request";
mail ($to, $subject, $info, "From: " . $name . $email);
echo "Your request has been sent!";

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try changing <input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit"> to type="submit"

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
```

to

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Also, you don't need a value with the submit, it's optional.

Answer (score 1):

To submit, it should have a input type submit

```
<input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
```

In addition, for the php part to check if the mail is sent, you should do:

```
if(mail ($to, $subject, $info, "From: " . $name . $email)){
  echo "Your request has been sent!";
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your input type to "submit":

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Then on your php file, I see you have a variable `$info`...

```
mail ($to, $subject, $info, "From: " . $name . $email);
```

But I don't see that it's actually defined anywhere. Before your mail function, give `$info` a value.

```
$info = "Hello World!";
```

Make sure to upload these files to a server - the php won't execute locally (unless you have a localhost running).

Comment: Thank you! I removed it from the form but forgot to remove it there.